# Can a const object, returned by value, still be moved?

Tags: c++

Example:

```
Foo return_a_foo()
{
    const auto a_foo = make_a_foo();

    //Work with, but do not mutate a_foo...

    return a_foo;       
}
```

If the compiler cannot employ RVO, I'd at least expect it to try and move a_foo. However, a_foo is const (but still about to go out of scope). Does it say anywhere in the standard that this is 100% guaranteed not to move (bummer) or is it implementation defined ?

Comment: You're returning a copy. It doesn't matter if the original (copied from) object is `const` or not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl : I'm hoping it gets moved, not copied, if it can't be RVO'd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a const object, returned by value, still be moved?

Some will be shocked to learn that the answer is, "sometimes, yes".

However, you have to give them more constructors in order to enable this. You would also have to either make members `mutable` or otherwise manually handle const-move-construction.

Proof:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { std::cout << "default c'tor\n"; }
    Foo(Foo const&&) { std::cout << "Foo const&&\n"; }
    Foo(Foo &&) { std::cout << "Foo &&\n"; }
    Foo(Foo const&) { std::cout << "Foo const&\n"; }
    Foo(Foo &) { std::cout << "Foo &\n"; }

};

const Foo make_a_foo()
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<const Foo>();
    return std::move(*p);
}

const Foo return_a_foo()
{
    const auto a_foo = make_a_foo();

    //Work with, but do not mutate a_foo...

    return a_foo;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = return_a_foo();
}
```

example output:

```
default c'tor
Foo const&&
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with use cases where `Foo(Foo const&&)` would make any sense.

Comment: @zett42 you're not alone. There probably are not many real-world use-cases. Nevertheless, the language permits it.

Comment: I don't think it's very shocking, considering that you can also manually apply `std::move` on a `const` object.

Comment: Hm. I thought that  `Foo(const Foo &&)` will always be chosen over `Foo(Foo &&)`. Isn't that why you normally go out of your way to `delete` signatures that use it?

Answer (score 2):

No, a `const T` can't be bound to a non-const `T&&`, so `a_foo` can't be moved from.

Your function returns a non-const `Foo` though, so `a_foo` will be copied to the return value.  The return value can then be moved from, since it's non-const.  See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffaf0304b03cabe5).

In reality all of those copies and moves will likely be elided.

Comment: generally correct, but strictly speaking wrong. see above.